# Disable csTransPie for a specific element

Tags: jquery

I use the library [csTransPie](http://www.pkoretic.net/csTransPie/).

How to disable the transformation for a specific element as an `<input type="file">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your item after the page is loaded:

**HTML**

```
<div id="file-container"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="csTransPie/csTransPie-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#file-container').html('<input type="file" />');​
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @GC., are u using the csTransPie? I just gave up 'cause I didn't find a way to make the input file work on IE8. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Towards the end of the file csTransPie.js (the unminified version), you'll find `$.fn.cTP = function() { ...` inside which you'll find:

```
$(':checkbox',this).cTPCheckBox();
$(':radio',this).cTPRadio();
$(':file',this).cTPFile();
$('select',this).cTPSelect();
```

Change this to:

```
$('.styleme:checkbox',this).cTPCheckBox();
$('.styleme:radio',this).cTPRadio();
$('.styleme:file',this).cTPFile();
$('select.styleme',this).cTPSelect();
```

And add the class `styleme` for all the elements you want styled by csTransPie. That should do it.